# React native Pod module

Tags: ios, react-native, cocoapods

We are trying to create a pod for use in a native app. The pod file will be an entry point into our SDK. And that SDK (pod) is using react-native. Basically, open a new screen with our content inside (third-party) native ios app.

Our problem is `s.dependency 'React'`.

```
require 'json'

package = JSON.parse(File.read(File.join(__dir__, 'package.json')))

Pod::Spec.new do |s|
  s.name         = "AwesomeSdk"
  s.version      = "0.0.1"
  s.summary      = "Payment SDK"
  s.description  = "Payment SDK from Wallee AG"

  s.homepage     = "https://en.awesome.com"
  s.license      = { :type => "MIT", :file => "LICENSE.md" }
  s.author       = { "Awesome Awesome" => "awesome@awesome.com" }
  s.platform     = :ios, "9.0"

  s.source = { :git => "https://gitlab.com/awesomesdk/frontend/mobile-sdk-android.git",  :branch => "WAL-78109-ios", :tag => "0.0.1" }
  s.source_files = "ios/sdk/AwesomeSdk/**/*.{h,m,swift}"


  s.swift_version = "5.0"

  s.dependency 'React'

end
```

We are able to connect our pod to another app outside of repository but when we want to install pods `pod install` it will start instaling react 0.11.0

```
Analyzing dependencies
Downloading dependencies
Installing React (0.11.0)
```

and after this it is carash with verri logn error:

```
[!] /bin/bash -c
set -e
npm install --production

npm WARN config production Use `--omit=dev` instead.
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! git dep preparation failed
npm ERR! command /Users/mynam/.nvm/versions/node/v16.15.1/bin/node /Users/mynam/.nvm/versions/node/v16.15.1/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js install --force --cache=/Users/mynam/.npm --prefer-offline=false --prefer-online=false --offline=false --no-progress --no-save --no-audit --include=dev --include=peer --include=optional --no-package-lock-only --no-dry-run
npm ERR! npm WARN using --force Recommended protections disabled.

...

npm ERR! npm ERR! /Users/mynam/Library/Caches/node-gyp/16.15.1/include/node/v8.h:11785:15: note: candidate constructor not viable: requires at least 3 arguments, but 1 was provided
npm ERR! npm ERR! ScriptOrigin::ScriptOrigin(
npm ERR! npm ERR!               ^
npm ERR! npm ERR! /Users/mynam/Library/Caches/node-gyp/16.15.1/include/node/v8.h:11816:15: note: candidate constructor not viable: requires at least 2 arguments, but 1 was provided
npm ERR! npm ERR! ScriptOrigin::ScriptOrigin(Isolate* isolate, Local<Value> resource_name,
npm ERR! npm ERR!               ^
npm ERR! npm ERR! ../src/contextify.cc:126:45: error: too few arguments to function call, single argument 'context' was not specified
npm ERR! npm ERR!         constructor.Reset(tmpl->GetFunction());
npm ERR! npm ERR!      

...
```

And the version is wrong we need RN 0.69 but when i specify it `s.dependency 'React', '~> 0.69.0'`

it can not find this module

```
Analyzing dependencies
[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "React":
  In Podfile:
    AwesomeSdk (from `../mobile-sdk-android`) was resolved to 0.0.1, which depends on
      React (~> 0.69.0)
```

We need to have React dependenci inside pod file... Any hint?